# Can Mathematica return a function in x from a definite integral in t (Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, part 1)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Hello: Is there a way Mathematica to transform a definite integral in t into a function in x, per the FTC1 equation:

```
g[x_] = (
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(2\), \(x\)]\(
\*FractionBox[\(
\*SuperscriptBox[\(t\), \(2\)] - 1\), \(
\*SuperscriptBox[\(t\), \(2\)] + 1\)] \[DifferentialD]t\)\)
```

The software just spins when I try this, either as '=' or ':='.
I've also tried both:

```
g[x] = Integrate[f[t], {t, 2, x}]
g[x] = Integrate[f[t], {x, 2, x}]
```

The first just spins.  The second returns:

```
((-1 + t^2) (-2 + x))/(1 + t^2)
```

...which is interesting, but not the function completely in x I was looking for.

I guess another way of putting my question is, can we get M. to handle upper and/or lower limits of integration as variables?

Thanks, TB

Comment: Perhaps `Integrate[(t^2 - 1)/(t^2 + 1), {t, 2, x}, GenerateConditions -> False]`?

Comment: You have to define a function with Blank, g[x_] not g[x].

Comment: Don't know what you exactly want. Maybe this `g[x_] = Integrate[f'[t], {t, 2, x}] `  yields `-f[2] + f[x] `

Comment: Thank you, all  Yes, 'GenerateConditions' does the trick.